# Cannot include header files correctly

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, header-files

I'm having an issue where I'm adding some includes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mysql.h>
```

Using this command to compile,

```
g++ -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ main.c -o program
```

When i remove the .h on MySQL  and stdio it says that it cannot find them, yet it works find on the unordered_map. Wtf?

Comment: Possibly because those two headers have the .h extension and unordered_map does not?

Comment: Header files without a `.h` are usually C++ includes. Header files with a `.h` are usually C #includes

Comment: @Paul R: Not really. Extensionless headers are part of the C++ standard library. OP should also be saying `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 1):

Some standard library headers are named for example "string", "vector" etc. You will find file "unordered_map" in your include dir, but you won't find file "mysql", only "mysql.h".

Answer (score 1):

Since the ages of C, most headers have had an extension which is typically `.h`, and they directly correspond to files in the system. In C++ the standard explicitly specifies certain library components as having include directives not including any extension, such as `<unordered_map>`. These library includes aren't even required to correspond to a file, just that they provide the required interface when included. By contrast, `mysql.h` and `stdio.h` and real files that must be included by exact name.

In the case of `stdio.h` the C++ library defines an include `<cstdio>` that includes all the features of C's `stdio.h` but puts them in the `std` namespace instead of global (which was the only option in C).

Answer (score 0):

The file name extension is not optional! The reason you can say

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

instead of

```
#include <unordered_map.h>
```

is because the file is actually called "unordered_map", no extension.

C++ does have the `cstdio` header which wraps C's `stdio.h` so you can include that instead; but as for `MySql.h`, I don't know whether they ship such a replacement.

Comment: `cstdio` is not the same as `stdio.h`, it wraps that into `std` namespace. Some implementations leave the symbols in the global namespace as a side-effect though, you should not count on that.

Comment: I didn't say it was the same, I said it wraps `stdio.h`.

Comment: In fact, there doesn't have to exist a *file* called `unordered_map` at all -- the standard only mandates that if you say `#include <unordered_map>`, then you get to use the various defined classes and functions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Interesting, never thought of it that way. It would be fun trying to step into an `std::unordered_map` function if there was no file :-)

Answer (score 0):

C++ omits the ".h" from it's system header files to differentiate them from the C header files. Detailed [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fstandlib%2Fref%2Fstdcpplib.htm) under the section titled "C++ Headers for the Standard C Library"